# Parent Custom Renderer not being called on iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I use a base content page for all pages in my app. I want to add a gradient to the content page so I created `LocalGradientContentPage` and had `BaseContentPage` inherit `LocalGradientContentPage`. Each platform has a custom renderer and everything works perfectly on Android. The android custom renderer is called when `BaseContentPage` is used. The issue is with iOS. iOS never calls the custom renderer when using `BaseContentPage`. It only calls the custom renderer if I use `LocalGradientContentPage` directly. All my classes follow.

LocalGradientContentPage.cs

```
namespace MyNamespace.Forms
{
    public class LocalGradientContentPage : ContentPage
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty EndColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(EndColor),
            typeof(Color),
            typeof(LocalGradientContentPage),
            Color.White);
        public Color EndColor
        {
            get => (Color)GetValue(EndColorProperty);
            set => SetValue(EndColorProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty StartColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(StartColor),
            typeof(Color),
            typeof(LocalGradientContentPage),
            Color.Black);
        public Color StartColor
        {
            get => (Color)GetValue(StartColorProperty);
            set => SetValue(StartColorProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Android: LocalGradientContentPageRenderer.cs

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(LocalGradientContentPage),typeof(LocalGradientContentPageRenderer))]
namespace MyNamespace.DroidRenderers
{
    public class LocalGradientContentPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        public LocalGradientContentPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        private Xamarin.Forms.Color StartColor { get; set; }
        private Xamarin.Forms.Color EndColor { get; set; }
        protected override void DispatchDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {
            var gradient = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, Height,
                StartColor.ToAndroid(),
                EndColor.ToAndroid(),
                Shader.TileMode.Mirror);
            var paint = new Paint()
            {
                Dither = true,
            };
            paint.SetShader(gradient);
            canvas.DrawPaint(paint);
            base.DispatchDraw(canvas);
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null || Element == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (!(e.NewElement is LocalGradientContentPage page)) return;

            StartColor = page.StartColor;
            EndColor = page.EndColor;
        }
    }
}
```

iOS:LocalGradientContentPage.cs

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(LocalGradientContentPage), typeof(LocalGradientContentPageRenderer))]
namespace MyNamespace.iOSRenderers
{
    public class LocalGradientContentPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (e.OldElement != null) return;
            if (e.NewElement is LocalGradientContentPage page)
            {
                var gradientLayer = new CAGradientLayer
                {
                    Frame = View.Bounds,
                    Colors = new CGColor[] { page.StartColor.ToCGColor(), page.EndColor.ToCGColor() }
                };
                View.Layer.InsertSublayer(gradientLayer, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

BaseContentPage.cs

```
public partial class BaseContentPage : LocalGradientContentPage
    {
        public BaseContentPage() : base()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

Using like this works:

```
<views:LocalGradientContentPage
    StartColor="Blue"
    EndColor="HotPink">
</views:LocalGradientContentPage>
```

Using like this does not work and the iOS `LocalGradientContentPageRenderer` is never called:

```
<views:BaseContentPage
    StartColor="Blue"
    EndColor="HotPink">
</views:LocalGradientContentPage>
```

I've do not have linking but just in case I did instantiate `LocalGradientContentPage` in `AppDelegate.cs`. It does hit the constructor when instantiated this way.

```
_ = new LocalGradientContentPage();
```

Also, as stated earlier, this is working fine in Android and calls the custom renderer when `BaseContentPage` is used.

I'm really at a loss as to why this isn't working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I use you code and add the `views:BaseContentPage` to a tabbedPage, it works well.

I use it like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
            xmlns:views="clr-namespace:App629"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="App629.TabbedPage1">
  <!--Pages can be added as references or inline-->
   
  <views:BaseContentPage
    StartColor="Blue"
    EndColor="HotPink"/>

  <ContentPage Title="Tab 2" />
  <ContentPage Title="Tab 3" />

    <views:BaseContentPage  StartColor="Red" EndColor="HotPink">
    </views:BaseContentPage>
</TabbedPage>
```

Some suggestions:

I'm using the latest Xamarin.forms version.

Check if there are any other codes in the BaseContentPage that affect the custom renderer?

Try the code as me to check if it works?

Add a breakPoint there in the custom renderer to check if it hit the code.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for trying this. I'll try a barebones project to see if i can figure out how i'm short circuiting this. thanks again.